# Pthread mutex lock assertion fails

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, assert

It's several days I'm trying to get ahead of this issue but seems like not my fault. I can't post any code because it's big enough. I'll try to explain it as better as I can.
First it is a `multithreaded server application` which receive request from multiple clients, also at same time, and elaborate it using master-workers (pool of threads) style with `AF_UNIX` sockets.
While it's running it often return this error :

> [name]: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.

I'm not able to replicate this error or to catch it with valgrind or gdb (I tried several times).
I use several global `pthread_mutex_t` initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`and I **never** destroy them. I'm pretty sure to lock and unlock them safely around the code like this:

1. `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);`
2. if something fails and I've to return from a thread: `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);` and `return (void*) -1;`
3. else : do things with shared variables
4. `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);`

I've read that it could be caused by a lower level race condition in `pthread_mutex_lock` file but I'm not sure.
By the way I would understand why this assertion could fails **generically**

Comment: Yes if I hold a lock before a  function call fail I unlock it and return. I do not grab the lock at the entry but just where I need it. Yes I cast `-1` to `void*` for `pthread_join`

Comment: I've to release the lock I own If the thread is going to be deleted no?

Comment: I do not check and I use normal pthread mutex. Every thread just try to lock it and after acquiring it they do some stuff and release it.

Comment: What you mention in comments is not entirely consistent with your question, and is the reason why a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is critical to answering your question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually indicates that the lock has become corrupted in some way. One possibility is that you are trying to lock a lock that was never initialized or has already been destroyed and not re-initialized. Another possibility is that some other piece of code is stomping on the mutex, possibly by accessing an array out of bounds or by accessing some memory after it has been freed.

Comment: Or perhaps he has a thread trying to unlock a mutex that that thread has not locked, or to lock a non-recursive one that it has already locked.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought that produced a different error, but now that I look at it, I think you're right -- this error can be produced by a thread trying to acquire a lock it already holds.

Comment: I just use pthread_mutex_normal and every thread do pthread_lock_acquire to gain the lock even if it could me already locked. Is it a problem?

Comment: @BetaRunner Yes. Unless the lock is specifically configured to be recursive, the result of locking a mutex you already hold is undefined. I would also add that if you have code that does something with a mutex and doesn't know whether or not it holds that mutex, there's a very good chance you're doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is possible to have this assert fail because of concurrency in gaining the lock at low level (in implementation it self)? For example if multiple threads try to lock simultaneously after one unlock it? I'm experiencing this error less if I slow down the entire system.

Comment: @BetaRunner Not unless your platform is horribly broken, which it almost certainly isn't.