# Can accessing mutex over a loop result in __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data-__owner == 0' failed

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads, mutex, assert

I have a function which is intermittently throwing the error

> __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data-__owner == 0' failed.

From my research till now I came to know the following cases in which this deadlock happens (please correct me if I am wrong):

1. If a thread has locked a mutex and again trying to lock the same mutex.
2. If the mutex the thread is trying to lock is either not initialized or destroyed/corrupted.
3. Corruption of memory stack.

The function has several sections using mutexes but a senior of mine pointed out a particular section and asked me to look into it, though even he couldn't pinpoint the problem but I am trusting his intuition.
This part is a for loop which is repeatedly calling a send() function which is writing data to a message queue.
Though from my review of the code till now I couldn't find any way in which the code might hit case 1 or 2 all mutexes are properly locked and released. Which leads me to suspect case 3, but the problem is that case 3 is very rare, but the occurrence of the issue is not that rare. Hence I am requesting anyone with a better understanding to take look into the code and confirm whether it is safe to call the send() function over in a loop, if yes than what might be causing mutex lock error. Here is the pseudo code:

```
class SafeMutex{
pthread_mutex_t s_mutex;
public:
void lock(){
pthread_mutex_lock(&s_mutex);
}
void unlock(){
pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_mutex);
}};

SafeMutex mymutex;

int send(){

mymutex.lock();

if(Condition A){
    }
else{
    if(Condition B){
                mymutex.unlock();
                return 1;
        }
    }
          mymutex.unlock();
if(Condition C){
          mymutex.lock();
          
          if(Condition B)
          { mymutex.unlock();
            return 1;
          }
          mymutex.unlock();
          if(Condition C)
          { return 1; 
          }
     }
return 0;
}

void SendMessages() {
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {  //this loop is calling send() with proper argument
        send();  
    }
}
```

PS: I am a noob still learning, please be easy on me :).

There is this question where the author has talked about lower level race condition in pthread_mutex_lock file, If anyone can tell further about this then it will be great: [Pthread mutex lock assertion fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635333/pthread-mutex-lock-assertion-fails)

Comment: Tried to give overview of the mutex locking within the function with the pseudo code as it will be simpler to understand. I am only concerned about the mutex operations. From my analysis into the function till now I can see that mutex is released in every case before function exits.

Comment: There was one stack overflow question where they mentioned "lower level race condition in pthread_mutex_lock file". Couldn't find further info on this. If someone knows further about this please tell too

Comment: In thhe function `send` you have unconditional `mymutex.lock()`, but in case when condition A is satisfied but C is not there is no corresponding `mymutex.unlock()`.

Comment: BTW, it is highly recommended to post the code with appropriate **indentation**. In the current form your code is completely unreadable. I have needed to copy paste it in my editor and perform indentation before I have been able to understand the branching.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks for pointing it out. There is a corresponding `mymutex.unlock()` for the unconditional `mymutex.lock()` at the very begining of the function. I missed it. Hope the psuedo code makes more sense now.

Comment: I don't see where your mutex is initialized (with `pthread_mutex_init`). But it is one of the possible causes for the error you got: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43302031/3440745.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I assure you that there is a seperate function in original code which uses `pthread_mutex_init()` ensuring that the mutex is initialised for our thread

Comment: So it is probably a memory corruption in some other part of your code. "but the problem is that case 3 is very rare, but the occurrence of the issue is not that rare." - Not sure what do you mean that given case is "rare": the code either has this behavior or not. A code which corrupts the memory should be fixed in any case. If you don't think that your code has such issue, then prepare [mcve]. It should be the **code** (not a pseudo-code), pasted directly into the question post (not a link to someone's repo),  which **reproduces** the problem (the error message about `__pthread_mutex_lock`)

Comment: Umm.... So for now can I deduce that the mutex locking and unlocking is happening properly in this function? The original code is very big, so I pasted the pseudo code only. Also the occurrence of the issue is somewhere like 4/152 runs. Can you give me some pointers that I can follow to verify whether the code is corrupting memory. Like should I look for other threads,functions which have access to this same mutex for instance? I have not encountered such problem before, thanks a bunch for your inputs till now @Tsyvarev

Comment: There are many tools which simplifies finding errors in the code. First, make sure to pass a compiler parameters for enable warnings during the compilation. In case of `gcc` options `-Wall`, `-Wextra` are quite useful. Make sure to fix all these warnings. (You may also pass `-Werror` for transform warnings to errors, so you won't miss them). Then, there are dynamic analyzers. E.g. you could instrument your code with [llvm sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers), so when your code will perform incorrect action, it will be immediately detected.

Comment: Got it. But I still think the problem is happening due to locking and unlocking mutex over a loop cuz I have another function which is doing the same thing and it's exiting with segmentation fault.